# GeckoView doesn't open target blank links or JS window.open calls

Tags: android, geckoview

`GeckoView` doesn't open links with `target="_blank"` attributes or `window.open` calls from JS in the current session - it simply does nothing on these interactions (same as iOS `WKWebview`).

How to default load new tabs/windows in the current `GeckoSession`?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [`onLoadRequest` docs](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.html#onLoadRequest(org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession,org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.LoadRequest)), you can override onLoadRequest with something like this (kotlin):

```
private fun createNavigationDelegate() = object : GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate {
    override fun onLoadRequest(session: GeckoSession, request: GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.LoadRequest): GeckoResult<AllowOrDeny> {
        if (request.target === NavigationDelegate.TARGET_WINDOW_NEW) {
            session.loadUri(request.uri)
        }

        return GeckoResult.fromValue(AllowOrDeny.ALLOW)
    }
}
```

From the docs linked above:

> For example, this can be used to override the behavior of TAGET_WINDOW_NEW requests, which defaults to requesting a new GeckoSession via onNewSession.